# How to change values which already saved in session

Tags: php, session

Sorry that my code is difficult to read but i tried my best to make it readable. I am saving the session values in this HTML form and I am trying to save the new data changes instead of the old one, but i can't do that.

```
<body>
<div class="div">
<?php                                         
  $id=$_GET["id"];
  if(isset($_SESSION['kundendaten'][$id])){                           
  $result=$_SESSION['kundendaten'][$id];                                     
 }                         
?>                  
</div> 

<form action="edit.php" method="post">
 <div>Name</div><input type="text"  name="name" value="<?php echo $result['vorname'];?>"   required>       
 <div>Familyname</div><input type="text"  name="familyname" value="<?php echo $result['nachname'];?>"  required>      
 <div>Date Of Birth</div><input type="text"  name="dateofbirth" value="<?php echo $result['geburtstag'];?>" required>       
 <div>Email</div><input type="Email" name="email" value="<?php echo $result['email'];?>" required>
 <div>Telefon</div><input type="text"  name="telefon" value="<?php echo $result['telefon'];?>" required>        
 <div>Adresse</div><input type="text"  name="adresse" value="<?php echo $result['adresse'];?>" required>   
   <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form> 

<?php           
 if (isset($_POST['vorname'])) {
  $result['vorname']=$_POST['vorname'];
  echo '<div>Vorname:</div><div class="div1">'.$result['vorname'].'</div>';
   }

?>   
 </form>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php                                         
  $id=$_GET["id"];
  if(isset($_SESSION['kundendaten'])){
  $_SESSION['kundendaten']=$id;
}                           
  $result=$_SESSION['kundendaten'];                                                             
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a session var, you have to directly change the value inside `$_SESSION`. So just do something like this

```
<?php           
if (isset($_POST['vorname'])) {
    $_SESSION['vorname'] = $_POST['vorname'];
    echo '<div>Vorname:</div><div class="div1">'.$_SESSION['vorname'].'</div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `$_SESSION` like any other variable:

```
$_SESSION['varname'] = $value;
```

But you must put

```
session_start();
```

At the top of your page if you want the `$_SESSION` array to stick around from page to page.

Answer (score 0):

you need to start the session on first. the session value take the id value

```
<?php                                         
      $id = $_GET["id"] ;
      session_start() ;
      if(isset($_SESSION['kundendaten']))
      {
      $_SESSION['kundendaten'] = $id ;
      }                           
      $result = $_SESSION['kundendaten'] ;                                                             
    ?>
```